# Find the index of a given permutation in the list of permutations in lexicographic order

Tags: algorithm, math, permutation, combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Given a string and permutation of the string. Find the index of this permuted string in the sorted list of the permutations of the string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131497/given-a-string-and-permutation-of-the-string-find-the-index-of-this-permuted-str)

This is an interview question. Let there is a list of permutations in lexicographic order. For example, `123`, `132`, `213`, `231`, `312`, `321`. Given a permutation find its index in such a list. For example, the index of permutation `213` is 2 (if we start from 0).

Trivially, we can use a `next_permutation` algorithm to generate a next permutation in lexicographic order, but it leads to O(N!) solution, which is obviously non-feasible. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution came into my mind (but I didn't test it yet).

The first digit is from range 1 to N, thus you can derive from the first digit whether your permutation is in which block of size (N-1)!

```
2*(2!) + X where X = 0..2!-1
```

Then you can recursively apply this to the next digits (which is one of (N-1)! permutations).

So with an arbitrary N you can do the following algorithm:

```
X = 0
while string <> ""
  X += ((first digit) - 1) * (N-1)!
  decrease all digits in string by 1 which are > first digit
  remove first digit from string
  N -= 1
return X
```

In your case:

```
X = 2
s = "213"
X += (2-1) * 2! => 2
s = "12"
X += (1-1) * 1! => 2
s = "1"
X += (1-1) * 0! => 2
```

Thus this algorithm is O(N^2).

Comment: I was able to follow most of your answer except for the first code block:`2*(2!) + X where X = 0..2!-1`. Would you mind explaining what this does please? I don't understand anything to the right of the equal sign.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the index of the first digit among the digits in the permutation by `(n-1)!` and add the index of the remaining permutation.

For example, `2` has index `1`, and the index of `13` is `0`, so the result is `1 * (3-1)! + 0 = 1 * 2 = 2`.

Answer (score 2):

- First element in the permutation gives you a subrange of `N!`
- Remove first element
- Renumber the remaining elements to remove gaps
- Recurse

Answer (score 1):

In C using recursion it will be something like this

```
int index(char *abc, int size)  
{   
   if(abc ==0 || *abc==0 || size == 0)  
  {  
    return 0;;  
  }  
  return ((abc[0] - '0') * pow(2,size-1)) + index(abc + 1, size -1);   
}
```