# Finding the Sorted Rank of a String

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search

So I'm working on a problem that was given to me as an interview question. I'm not quite fully there, and could use some guidance as to how to approach this algorithm. The gist of it is this: you have "words" of the same length that contain the same letters (i.e., read and dear). The requested program would allow you to input any word you desire (e.g, "deinstitutionalization") and get the location of that word within the context of all the other letters sorted alphanumerically, without having created an entire list of possibilities. So, for example, deinstitutionalization may be in position 156363363 of the possible "words" that d, e, i, n ,s, t, u, o, a, l, and z make up with a length of 22 characters.

I've seen a lot of different paradigms used for generating the permutations of a string, but I haven't been able to put any of them together to solve this problem. Is there a specific algorithm that would be at least somewhat suitable for this? Are there any suggestions on how to approach this? I'd like to figure this out on my own, but just need a bit of a bump to get there.

Comment: Was `deinstitutionalization` part of the interview question, or did you make that one up?  The reason I ask is that repeated letters make this problem much harder to solve.

Comment: @user3386109: On the contrary; repeated letters make the problem much easier.

Comment: @swamp56: It appears that you need to be more precise in this question. Did you mean "the index in the list of all permutations of the letters" (in which case the count of each letter is significant) or "the index in the list possible words made from the same set of letters"? (in which case the count is not relevant).

Comment: Have you already read these articles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146910/finding-the-lexicographic-index-of-a-permutation-of-a-given-array and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921860/find-the-index-of-a-given-permutation-in-the-list-of-permutations-in-lexicograph

Comment: I am supposed to find out where in the list of all permutations of the given letters (repeated included) that the word exists given that the list is sorted alphabetically. I was told not to generate a list and then search for that particular word in it.

Comment: So given "deinstitutionalization", is "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" a valid permutation?  If so, @rici has already posted the correct answer.

Comment: Hello, no it wouldn't be because it needs to be made up of the same letters as the input. This would be, however:

ednisitttuoinalzitaoin

Comment: @Swamp56 In that case David's answer applies

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks! I'll take a look at it when I get some time this week. I'd like to note that this is for a junior-level developer position. Is something this complicated a typical scenario for these interviews?

Answer (score 1):

Your hint is in the early half of [these slides](http://web.info.uvt.ro/~mmarin/lectures/GTC/curs-02.pdf), from which I have pulled out the two main ideas.

These two general ideas which may help you, but will not solve the problem entirely, because you still need to figure out how to map your possibly duplicated letters onto ranked numbers.

1. All permutations sharing the same first element k are ranked `(k-1)(n-1)!` to `k(n − 1)! − 1`.
2. You can delete the first element to recursively find the rank of the remaining permutation.

Answer (score 1):

The sorted rank of a string is the number of distinct permutations that are less than it (or equal to it, for ranks that start at 1). A permutation P is less than a permutation P' if and only if P and P' have a common prefix, followed by a letter for P that is less than the corresponding letter for P', followed by arbitrary letters. The simplest way that I know of to compute permutation rank efficiently is to iterate over the length of this common prefix, then iterate over the substitutions for the next position that decrease the letter there, then add the number of permutations of the residual suffix. It's fairly easy to prove that each lesser permutation is counted exactly once.

I know that this idea works because I've implemented it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22643546/2144669 .

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 subparts to your question

1. generate a hashcode for word combinations , so r,e,a,d will have a different combination that r,e,a  will have . But they will have the same combination that d,e,a and r will have. 
   So you need to find the unique elements in a word, sort them and create a hashcode for this list .You can easily use String's hashcode for this.  If you are working on a list of words from which you generate this, it is straightforward and can be implemented as a Trie. However, if you generate them as combinations it is very tricky
2. For each of the word, you have to compare the letters and insert them accordingly, you can use String compare To to generate this. You probably need a Map where key is the hascode derived in step 1 and value is a balanced tree or a map .
3. For a given word, you need to find the ranking for that word in the sorted structure. If you have a sortedHashmap or a balanced tree , you can  easily do that

I will probably go for a trie where each node in the trie has a balanced tree.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding your answer, you would need about [1 Yottabyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yottabyte) to hold all the words and you would need to wait quite a bit to fill up that yottabyte of space. That seems a bit wasteful since there exists an O(n) solution that only needs constant space.

Comment: @NiklasB., I think you are misunderstanding my answer. Where are you thinking that I am holding too much memory for the objects. I need memory for the trie and the each node needs a memory for the map. an object is stored only at one node.