# Difference between permutations

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, permutation

Is there a way to compute quantitatively the *distance* between two permutations?

Suppose we have the following two sequences of elements:

```
A = {0, 1, 2, 3}
B = {0, 3, 2, 1}
```

I could say that the permutation `B` differs from `A` because:

- I would require **1** swap operation in order to transform `B` to `A`
- There are **2** elements within `B` that have an index that is different for the same elements in `A`

Are there other ways to compare and describe the difference between those two?

The main goal is to define an algorithm that is able to approach the second permutation `B` to the first one `A`, such that if all the steps of this procedure are applied the outcome would be the permutation `A` itself. 
But in order to to that I think it should be best to define first a sensible procedure that describes how much `B` differs from `A`.

Is there any known algorithm that allows to approach on permutation to another?

Comment: How do you define the transformation operation? is it just a сircular shift?

Comment: @zaratustra The transformation is the set of swaps between two elements of the permutation.

Comment: Could the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) be related to your problem ?

Comment: @kebs Could be Hamming distance, could be [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), the OP could even be looking for [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). The requirements are unclear.

Comment: This can help also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1410088/how-to-determine-a-kind-of-distance-between-two-permutations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different ways to define the difference between two sequences. To name a few:

**[Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance)**: the number of positions at which elements differ.

```
hamming(A, B)
  B[1] is different than A[1] and B[3] is different than A[3]
=> 2
```

**[Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)**: the minimum number of modifications necessary to get from one sequence to another.

```
levenshtein(A, B)
  replace B[1] with A[1] and replace B[3] with A[3]
=> 2
```

**[Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance)**: an extension of the former that takes into account transpositions.

```
damerau_levenshtein(A, B)
  transpose B[3] with B[1]
=> 1
```

Based upon your given example, you are interested in tracking transpositions and therefore Damerau–Levenshtein distance is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Distance between permutations can be distance between lexicographic indexes of the permutations.

How to find lexicographic index [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146910/finding-the-lexicographic-index-of-a-permutation-of-a-given-array) [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013373/finding-the-index-of-a-given-permutation) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131497/find-the-index-of-a-given-permutation-in-the-sorted-list-of-the-permutations-of).