# Printing a unique order of 4 items from a unique input between 0-23

Tags: algorithm, factorial

There are 4 items
-I1
-I2
-I3
-I4

The possible order of these items is 4! = 24.
In order to save space, I need to use only 5 bits to represent each of the unique 24 permutations.

What is the most efficient way to reverse engineer a specific priority order in the list if we just have a number as input ?
In general, how do we do this for n items ? Is there any algorithm in place ?

Comment: Google suggests [Lehmer code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_code) for encoding permutations as numbers.

Comment: The reverse, which may also help - [Find the index of a given permutation in the sorted list of the permutations of a given string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5131497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lehmer code can be used for this. This looks like a pretty decent guide on how to do that: http://www.2ality.com/2013/03/permutations.html